# Сделать цветную область внутри чернобелого background-image

Tags: javascript, html, css3

Есть div с шириной 100% и высотой 100vh и заданной ему фоновой картинкой в качестве background; также заданы background-size: cover и filter: grayscale(100%). Нужно расположить внутри него блок, который в занимаемом пространстве будет делать фоновую картинку цветной.

Я пробовал через псевдоэлемнты, но пока не выходит. Ай нид хэлп!

Comment: при каком событии хочешь делать, чтобы картинка была цветной ?

Comment: в общем события нет, есть секция с ч.б фоном, внутри неё должен быть акцентный элемент отменяющий grayscale. Переиспользовать картинку не хотелось бы, ибо теряется адаптивность.

Comment: сделать дырку в элементе - нельзя

Comment: @Grundy есть свойство `backdrop-filter`, наверное с ним можно что-то придумать https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/backdrop-filter

Comment: @МихаилКамахин, нельзя, потому что он добавляет фильтр, а не снимает. А в вопросе речь, как раз про то, чтобы снять фильтре `grayscale` под элементом

Answer (score 3):

Можно добавить класс, который добавляет `grayscale`

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.intro {
  min-height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.intro::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

.intro.grayscale::before {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.intro__content {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro grayscale">
  <div class="intro__content">С grayscale</div>
</div>
<div class="intro">
  <div class="intro__content">А это без grayscale</div>
</div>
```

Или можно использовать `backdrop-filter`:

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.intro {
  min-height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: white;
}

.intro > * {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.intro::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/2000/1000) no-repeat center;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: -1;
}

.intro > * + * {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.intro__content {
  padding: 40px 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.intro .grayscale {
  backdrop-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.intro .huerotate {
  backdrop-filter: hue-rotate(120deg);
}

.intro .invert {
  backdrop-filter: invert(70%);
}

.intro .brightness {
  backdrop-filter: brightness(60%);
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <div class="intro__content grayscale">
  grayscale 100%
  </div>
  <div class="intro__content huerotate">
  hue-rotate 120deg
  </div>
  <div class="intro__content invert">
  invert 70%
  </div>
  <div class="intro__content brightness">
  brightness 60%
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: в вопросе речь про то, что у тебя у `intro` стоит `grayscale`, а у вложенных, что-то, что снимает этот grayscale

Comment: @Grundy напишите ответ, я не понимаю, про что вы говорите

Comment: поставь в своем втором сниппете `<div class="intro grayscale">` и сделай так, чтобы в `<div class="intro__content">` фон был не серым, а цветным. Вот о чем речь в вопросе